How to sort numbers before letters with linguistic sorting?
In an Oracle SQL query which uses binary sorting rules, numbers are sorted before letters. But if the query uses a language specific collation to enable linguistic sorting, then numbers are sorted after letters.
Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/BBfvb2lh
This differs from e.g. .NET sorting, where even with linguistic sorting the numbers are sorted before letters.
Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/65G3na
How can I use linguistic sorting and sort numbers before letters in an Oracle SQL query?

I've got a simpler solution in my follow up question:
The order is correct if I replace COLLATE XGERMAN_AI with COLLATE GENERIC_M_AI.
Extended examples:
Oracle: https://dbfiddle.uk/TOzViGhK
.NET: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gytC9a

Assuming you can accept sorting numbers first, followed by everything else second, then you could use the following logic:
SELECT val
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(val, '^[0-9]') THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,  -- numbers first
    val;                                                     -- then sort by val


This seems to work, thanks. But my actual query sorts 6 columns by linguistic sorting rules. That would mean I'd have to add 6 additional order by parts, correct?

Yes, if you want to sort by 6 separate columns, then generally your ORDER BY clause would have 6 parts (or in the context of my answer, 6 x 2 = 12 parts).

I've updated the sample links in my question to also include rows which don't have the numbers at the beginning. I'd like to have those sorted "correctly" too.

You should ask a new question; this one has been answered.

Sorry, I've reverted the edits in the question and created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79022731/how-to-sort-all-numbers-before-letters-with-linguistic-sorting

Try this bro:
create table t(val varchar2(100));

insert into t 
  select 'AD4' from dual union all
  select 'aA1' from dual union all
  select 'äB2' from dual union all
  select 'aC3' from dual union all
  select '1' from dual union all
  select '2' from dual union all
  select 'XAA2' from dual union all
  select 'X1A1' from dual;
  commit;
  
SELECT val
FROM t
ORDER BY substr(REGEXP_REPLACE(val, '[[:alpha:]]'),0)

This answer is almost the same the link you post (How to sort numbers before letters with linguistic sorting?).
Using '[[:alpha:]]') in this case wiil consider number first inside

This doesn't work. The order is completely wrong.
