How to sort all numbers before letters with linguistic sorting?
In an Oracle SQL query which uses binary sorting rules, numbers are sorted before letters. But if the query uses a language specific collation to enable linguistic sorting, then numbers are sorted after letters.
Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/xfXRj2sv
Extended example: https://dbfiddle.uk/vY2ovuam
This differs from e.g. .NET sorting, where even with linguistic sorting the numbers are sorted before letters.
Example with the expected order: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RulPpO
Extended example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gytC9a
How can I use linguistic sorting and sort numbers before letters in an Oracle SQL query?
Note: This question is similar to How to sort numbers before letters with linguistic sorting?, but expanded to also include numbers in the middle of a string.

You can get a result that matches your .NET fiddle with GENERIC_M_AI or UCA_0620_DUCET_AI multilingual collation - even if you only have one language to handle:
select val
from t
order by val COLLATE GENERIC_M_AI




VAL




1


2


aA1


äB2


aC3


AD4


X1A1


XAA2



select val
from t
order by val COLLATE UCA0620_DUCET_AI




VAL




1


2


aA1


äB2


aC3


AD4


X1A1


XAA2



fiddle

Thanks. It seems like the following collations all work like german culture sensitive sorting in .NET: Fiddle. Do you know cases where they produce different results?

No idea, sorry. From the documentation I linked to, the Oracle one seems to be based on ISO-14651, so I guess you can try to find out if .NET is the same.

I think you are going in right direction. You just need to sort lower characters first -
SELECT val
  FROM t
 ORDER BY LOWER(val) COLLATE BINARY_AI;

Demo.

Interesting. BINARY_AI seems to work like german culture sensitive sorting in .NET. And this seems to work even without calling lower. Or do you know a case where lower makes a difference?

Try this:
create table t(val varchar2(100));

insert into t 
  select 'AD4' from dual union all
  select 'aA1' from dual union all
  select 'äB2' from dual union all
  select 'aC3' from dual union all
  select '1' from dual union all
  select '2' from dual union all
  select 'XAA2' from dual union all
  select 'X1A1' from dual;
  commit;
  
SELECT val
FROM t
ORDER BY substr(REGEXP_REPLACE(val, '[[:alpha:]]'),0)

This answer is almost the same the link you post (How to sort numbers before letters with linguistic sorting?).
Using '[[:alpha:]]') in this case, will consider number first in the middle of the string.
The result:

aA1
1
X1A1
XAA2
äB2
2
aC3
AD4


This script in working as expected. Its not giving the correct result to OP.

This doesn't work. The order is completely wrong.
